# write source files to output in custom asp.net server control

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I am writing own server-side control.I need to use some images in this control.How can I write to output image file [or any other file] and then access it?

```
       protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
       .......
       output.Write("some file");
       string endResult = "<img src= how to access this file? />"
       output.Write(endResult);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Option 1: Embed It Directly

You can embed images (and other files) directly into webpages using a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).  Something like:

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    ............
    byte[] rawImgData = []; //add your data here, maybe from a FileStream
    String imgMimeType = "[img mime type, eg image/png]";
    String encodedImgData = Convert.ToBase64String(rawImageData);

    output.Write(String.Format("<img src=\"data:{0},{1}\" />", imageMimeType, encodedImageData))
}
```

As outlined in the link, this approach has lots of disadvantages.  If you'll be serving the same images with every request to your control, you should really use static files.

### Option 2: Save to the server and map it

Assuming your IIS worker account (normally called IUSR) has write access to some location on the server, you can save it with `Server.MapPath` and send the actual link out.

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    ............
    byte[] rawImgData = []; //add your data here, maybe from a FileStream

    FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(Server.MapPath(virtualPath))
    fileStream.Write(rawImgData, 0, rawImgData.Length)
    fileStream.Close()

    output.Write(String.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" />", virtualPath))
}
```

For repetitive requests, this definitely the best option.

## Option 3: Store it in memory and serve via a second page

You can store the raw data in `Session` (or another temporary in-memory storage of your choice), send a link with an identifier, and server it from another page.  Something like:

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    ............
    byte[] rawImgData = []; //add your data here, maybe from a FileStream

    Session["MyImgTempStorage"] = rawImgData;

    output.Write("<img src=\"ServeImgTempStorage.ashx?file=MyImgTempStorage\");
}
```

and make a generic handler called ServeImgTempStorage.ashx like this:

```
public class ServeImgTempStorage : System.Web.IHttpHandler
{

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string fileKey = context.Request.QueryString("file");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileKey)) {
        return;
    }

    byte[] rawData = context.Session(fileKey);

    context.Response.Write(rawData);
    context.Response.ContentType = "[your mime type.  you can force a download with attachment;]";
    context.Response.End();
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get { return false; }
}

}
```

You'll need to make sure you use *session unique* identifiers for every file served in this way, or you will overwrite data.

NOTE: My C# syntax may be off, I normally write in VB.